# Create a c program that takes two dates and output the number of days between them

Tags: c

This is my code to find the days in between days. For example 03 15 to 03 24 have 9 days between each other.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int mm,dd,yy, mm2, dd2, yy2;

    printf("Please enter in first date (MM/DD/YYYY format): ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&mm,&dd,&yy);

    printf("Please enter in second date (MM/DD/YYYY format): ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&mm2,&dd2,&yy2);

    if(yy>=2000 && yy<=2019) {//check year if it between 2000 to 2019
        if(mm>=1 && mm<=12){  //check month
            if((dd>=1 && dd<=31) && (mm==1 || mm==3 || mm==5 || mm==7 || mm==8 || mm==10 || mm==12))        //check the days of these months.
                printf("The first date is valid.\n");
            else if((dd>=1 && dd<=30) && (mm==4 || mm==6 || mm==9 || mm==11)) //check the days of these months.
                printf("The first date is valid.\n");
            else if((dd>=1 && dd<=28) && (mm==2)) //check the days of these month because February only have 28 days when its not a leap year
                printf("The first date is valid.\n");
            else if(dd==29 && mm==2 && (yy%400==0 ||(yy%4==0 && yy%100!=0))) // a leap year check
                printf("The first date is valid.\n");
            else
                printf("The first day is invalid.\n");  // run if the user have enter in a invalid day
        } else {
            printf("The first month is not valid.\n"); // run if the user have enter in a invalid month
        }
    } else {
        printf("The first year is not valid.\n"); // run if the user have enter in a invalid year
    }   

    if(mm < mm2) { // check to see if mm2 is greater than mm
        int s = dd2-dd; 
        s=s+dd2;

        for (mm=mm;mm<mm2+1;mm++) {
            s=s+mm;
        }
        printf("The total number states which is strictly between given two dates is: %d\n", s);
    } else if(mm == mm2) {// check to see if it is in the same month
        if(dd <= dd2) { // check to see if day2 is greater to equal to day1
            // print out the number that are between those days
            printf("The total number states which is strictly between given two dates is: %d\n", dd2-dd);  
        } else {
            printf("Second date precedes the first date\n"); // if the second is greater then the first date, it will print this out
        }
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

For some reason when I enter in `02/10/2019` and `03/07/2019`. I get `4` for the days in between which is wrong but when I do `01/01/2019` and `12/03/2019`, I get `81` which is correct.

Comment: Wrong tag. It's a c code not c++ code

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: The correct way to solve such problems is to first create a function `d(x)` which finds days between `x` and an *epoch* like 1970/1/1, and then you can find difference between `x`, `y`, you will have it as `d(y) - d(x)`.

Comment: In addition, try to find a generic way using modulus and floor functions. Do not use conditional statements. It can be done.

Comment: What is `int s = mm-dd;` suppose to do?

Comment: Sorry about that. Its supposed to be the calculation of the dd2 and dd

Comment: Research `mktime(), difftime()`.

Comment: You probably need to create a function to read one date, and call it twice to read the two dates.  You don't show the input for the other date, which is probably a good idea if it is just an almost-repeat of the code for the first date.  Using functions is important.  Kernighan and Plauger summarized it neatly in their book "The Elements of Programming Style" • The subroutine call permits us to summarize the irregularities in the argument list, where we can see quickly what is going on. • The subroutine itself summarizes the regularities of the code, so repeated patterns need not be used.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void days(int,int,int,int,int,int);
int month(int,int);
int mon[12]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

 main()
  {
  int a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2;
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter first date(dd mm yyyy) : ");
  scanf("%d%d%d",&a1,&b1,&c1);
  printf("\nEnter second date(dd mm yyyy) : ");
  scanf("%d%d%d",&a2,&b2,&c2);
  if(c2>=c1)// checking which date is lesser
  days(c1,c2,b1,b2,a1,a2);
  else
  days(c2,c1,b2,b1,a2,a1);
  getch();
  }

 void days(int y1,int y2,int m1,int m2,int d1,int d2)
  {
  int count=0,i;
  for(i=y1;i<y2;i++)//just adding days
    {
    if(i%4==0)//leap year
    count+=366;
    else
    count+=365;
    }
  count-=month(m1,y1);//sub month
  count-=d1;//day
  count+=month(m2,y2);//add month
  count+=d2;//day
  if(count<0)
  count=count*-1;
  printf("The no. of days b/w the 2 dates = %d days",count);
  }

 int month(int a,int yy)
  {
  int x=0,c;
  for(c=0;c<a-1;c++)
    {
   if(c==1)// feb
      {
      if(yy%4==0)
      x+=29;
      else
      x+=28;
      }
    else
    x+=mon[c];//get no. Of days in the month
    }
  return(x);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got one answer, and that one looks really good. I am adding answer to give you an optional method. Ultimately, you can always convert the date strings to timestamps. After that, you can look for the time difference between the two dates by subtracting the second date's timestamp to the first date time stamp. If that yields negative, that is a precedent day. If not, that is all fine.

To be able to do that, you can use mktime() and struct tm from . When you use "time.h" you would still need to validate your dates like now. It just, it would be easier on the calculation.

For tm_year from struct tm, you would need to subtract the year value to 1900. Also, it seemed that you only wanted your program to work for dates from the year 2000 - 2019. Thus, 19 years. Thus, I think a long or int_64 should be able to hold the maximum seconds different between two dates. Also, mktime() return value are seconds.

Take notice that I did not write the code to calculate where date 2 is before date 1. Thus, if you attempt to calculate that, it might give you an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int mm,dd,yy, mm2, dd2, yy2;

    printf("Please enter in first date (MM/DD/YYYY format): ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&mm,&dd,&yy);

    printf("Please enter in second date (MM/DD/YYYY format): ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&mm2,&dd2,&yy2);

    if(yy>=2000 && yy<=2019) {//check year if it between 2000 to 2019
        if(mm>=1 && mm<=12){  //check month
            if((dd>=1 && dd<=31) && (mm==1 || mm==3 || mm==5 || mm==7 || mm==8 || mm==10 || mm==12))        //check the days of these months.
                printf("The first date is valid.\n");
            else if((dd>=1 && dd<=30) && (mm==4 || mm==6 || mm==9 || mm==11)) //check the days of these months.
                printf("The first date is valid.\n");
            else if((dd>=1 && dd<=28) && (mm==2)) //check the days of these month because February only have 28 days when its not a leap year
                printf("The first date is valid.\n");
            else if(dd==29 && mm==2 && (yy%400==0 ||(yy%4==0 && yy%100!=0))) // a leap year check
                printf("The first date is valid.\n");
            else {
                printf("The first day is invalid.\n");  // run if the user have enter in a invalid day
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            printf("The first month is not valid.\n"); // run if the user have enter in a invalid month
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        printf("The first year is not valid.\n"); // run if the user have enter in a invalid year
        return 1;
    }   

    struct tm firstDate;
    struct tm secondDate;

    firstDate.tm_sec = 0;
    firstDate.tm_min = 0;
    firstDate.tm_hour = 0;
    firstDate.tm_mday = dd;       
    firstDate.tm_mon = mm;
    firstDate.tm_year = yy-1900;
    firstDate.tm_isdst = 0;

    secondDate.tm_sec = 0;
    secondDate.tm_min = 0;
    secondDate.tm_hour = 0;
    secondDate.tm_mday = dd2;       
    secondDate.tm_mon = mm2;
    secondDate.tm_year = yy2-1900;
    secondDate.tm_isdst = 0;

    long epochFirstDate = (long) mktime(&firstDate);

    long epochSecondDate = (long) mktime(&secondDate);

    long dayDifferent = (epochSecondDate - epochFirstDate);

    if ( dayDifferent > 0 ) dayDifferent = dayDifferent / 60 / 60 / 24;

    if ( dayDifferent > -1 ) 
        printf("The total number states which is strictly between given two dates is: %lu\n", dayDifferent);
    else 
        printf("Second date precedes the first date\n"); // if the second is greater then the first date, it will print this out

    return 0;
}
```